# Saving Python Pickled objects in MySQL db

Tags: python, mysql, django, pickle

I am pickling Python Objects in Django and saving it in MySQL db.
So far i have followed these simple rules:

1. `cPickle.dumps(object)` #to convert python object to pickled object
2. `cPickle.loads(pickled_object)` # to load back the python object from pickled object
3. My Django `Model Field` is `Text Field`
4. MySQL db field Type is `longblob` Attributes `binary`
5. MySQL db encoding is `utf8_unicode_ci`

Unfortunately i am getting following error while loading back python object.

```
Type Error: ('an integer is required', <type 'datetime.date'>, ('x07xb6x0bx06',))
```

It seems to me by looking on error value `x07xb6x0bx06` this is an encoding problem.
Did i miss some important step?? Can any one help me to solve this problem??

Comment: Do you have a specific reason to use pickle? It's a binaryish format and only usable by python. If you have a choice, would JSON not be a better option?

Comment: JSON does not server my purpose, I try to use `json.dumps` but got this error `some_object is not JSON serializable`. And the object is pure Pythonic.

Comment: You should try to make that object serialisable too. It's a *big* help to have human readable stuff in your db when you're trying to find a bug.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are trying to store the output of `cPickle.dumps` in a `VARCHAR` column, then your issue is that you are trying to store a byte-string in a character column.  The fix in that case is to encode your object as `unicode(base64.encode(cPickle.dumps(myobject)))` and then store it.

Alternatively:

```
object2varchar = lambda obj: unicode(base64.encode(cPickle.dumps(obj)))
store(object2varchar([1, 'foo']))
```

Answer (score 1):

one more rule: connect to mysql with option `charset=utf8`?

UPD1:
Sometimes it is a good idea to look at the complete SQL query, I usually do it that way:

```
>>> conn = MySQLdb.connect(**db_params)
>>> "INSERT INTO tbl VALUES (%s)" % conn.literal((your_pickled_item, ))
```

Comment: @aamir-adnan, have you tried to save and read a new item instead of reading already saved?

Comment: Good question, yes i checked it, it works fine when i convert and restore python object within code, it is problem with db while reading or not storing properly. What should i do? please help.

Comment: @aamir-adhan, I meant that the previous items might have been saved in a wrong encoding and noew can now be properly read.

Comment: Instead of using Django Model (confused with behavior of Django Models `Text field` with MySQL `blob field`), i `directly` makes a connection to db and store the pickled object directly in db. But again same error :-(

Comment: yes i always update the fields and then read the new value. I am not reading old saved values.

Answer (score 0):

Newtover's answer is probably the correct one, but have a look at

https://github.com/bradjasper/django-pickledfield

It really saved me some time, and can store pretty much anything you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, now!
django-picklefield
https://pypi.org/project/django-picklefield/

To use, just define a field in your model:

```
>>> from picklefield.fields import PickledObjectField
... class SomeObject(models.Model):
...     args = PickledObjectField()
```

and assign whatever you like (as long as it's picklable) to the field:

```
>>> obj = SomeObject()
>>> obj.args = ['fancy', {'objects': 'inside'}]
>>> obj.save()
```