# Remove or edit entry saved with Python pickle

Tags: python, binary, pickle

I basically do sequences of dump and load, but at some point I want to delete one of the loaded entries. How can I do that? Is there a way to remove, or edit entries saved with Python pickle/cpickle?

Edit: The data is saved with pickle in a binary file.

Comment: How are you saving the items? On a file? Also, what have you tried until now?

Comment: Yes, they are saved in a file

Comment: @Alex Deleting from a file at an arbitrary position is not trivial. Have you considered an approach with a db?

Comment: I have thought about a database, but I wanted something more lightweight. I was thinking that it would be nice if pickle saves the position after loading some data, and maybe I can use that information?

Comment: The pickle only reflects what you save. If you load, remove an entry from the structure, then save again, the newly saved version will not include the deleted data.

Comment: @MartijnPieters loading ALL the data, modifying the structure and saving it again is a solution, but not a very fast one. Besides this, at some point the data loaded could be too big for the memory.

Comment: @Alex As far as I understand, you want to be able to delete from arbitrary places in the file. This however will require you to write the whole file again. Consider SQLite (least effort) as an alternative to a file if you are not comfortable with rewriting the whole file.

Comment: @Alex: then you need something more sophisticated. Either use a SQL database, or use the ZODB (which can handle more fine-grained pickling).

Comment: @DJV I will probably do that after I realize pickle won't not help me with this.

Comment: @Alex Actually, pickle can help you. You can write the pickled object as a TextField.

Comment: @DJV You mean to write it as a TextField in a database, right?

Comment: @Alex Yes. I've tried it with MySQL and it works fine. Something like `pickle.loads(b64decode(value))` and `unicode(b64encode(pickle.dumps(value, pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)))` does the trick. This also seems to cover it - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8150078/saving-python-pickled-objects-in-mysql-db

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To delete a pickled object from a binary file you *must* rewrite the whole file.
The `pickle` module doesn't deal with modifications at arbitrary portions of the stream, so there is no built-in way of doing what you want.

Probably the simplest alternative to binary files is to use the [`shelve`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/shelve.html) module.

This module provides a `dict` like interface to a database containing the pickled data, as you can see from the example in the documentation:

```
import shelve

d = shelve.open(filename) # open -- file may get suffix added by low-level
                          # library

d[key] = data   # store data at key (overwrites old data if
                # using an existing key)
data = d[key]   # retrieve a COPY of data at key (raise KeyError if no
                # such key)
del d[key]      # delete data stored at key (raises KeyError
                # if no such key)
flag = key in d        # true if the key exists
klist = list(d.keys()) # a list of all existing keys (slow!)

# as d was opened WITHOUT writeback=True, beware:
d['xx'] = [0, 1, 2]    # this works as expected, but...
d['xx'].append(3)      # *this doesn't!* -- d['xx'] is STILL [0, 1, 2]!

# having opened d without writeback=True, you need to code carefully:
temp = d['xx']      # extracts the copy
temp.append(5)      # mutates the copy
d['xx'] = temp      # stores the copy right back, to persist it

# or, d=shelve.open(filename,writeback=True) would let you just code
# d['xx'].append(5) and have it work as expected, BUT it would also
# consume more memory and make the d.close() operation slower.

d.close()       # close it
```

The database used is `ndbm` or `gdbm`, depending on the platform and the libraries available.

Note: this works well if the data is not moved to an other platform. If you want to be able to copy the database to an other computer then `shelve` wont work well, since it does not provide guarantees regarding which library will be used. In this case using an explicit SQL database is probably the best option.

Comment: Thanks! The only drawback is that [`shelve`] is quite slow, but probably not slower than re-writing the whole file.

Comment: @Alex I'm not sure, but probably using the `update` method instead of settings the keys one by one might be faster(since this give the chance to do a single bulk transaction instead of many writes).

Comment: So this is supposed to work with pickled objects? Didn't work in my case: `dbm.error: db type could not be determined`

Comment: @CGFoX That seems like a corrupt db file. Anyway you should try to open your own question about that.