# Saving an unknown object type into database in Django

Tags: mysql, json, django, pickle

I have the following model:

```
class Parameter(models.Model):
    par_type = = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    value = models.TextField()
```

Majority of the time the `value` field will store a number (`value=3.2118`). But sometimes I want to assign a list of other object IDs (like `value="[32, 22, 45]"`) or a string object (like `value="pass"`), etc. I will use `value` field in functions like the ones below based on the value of `par_type`:

```
def foo(par): # par is a Parameter object.
    return float(par.value) / 2

def bar(par):
    # Some code to convert a par to a list of objects
    object_list = get_objects(par) 
    # Return a random object from list
    return random.choice(object_list)
```

I don't want to write a piece of code for every possible object type. Ideally there is one `decompose()` function to use everywhere. I thought of saving object as `pickle` or `JSON` type (saw it from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8150078/saving-python-pickled-objects-in-mysql-db)). But I couldn't figured out how to do it. I'm using MySQL db.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try like this using [BinaryField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#binaryfield):

```
import pickle

class Parameter(models.Model):
    _value = models.BinaryField()

    def set_data(self, data):
        self._value = pickle.dumps(data)

    def get_data(self):
        return pickle.loads(self._value)

    value = property(get_data, set_data)
```

Usage:

```
In: b = Foo.objects.create(value=1)

In: b.value
Out: 1

In: b = Foo.objects.create(value={1:1,2:2})

In: b.value
Out: {1: 1, 2: 2}

In: b = Foo.objects.create(value=[1,1])

In: b.value
Out: [1, 1]
```

FYI, you can't store `pass` because it is not a Python Object, but its part of syntax. Instead of pass, consider using `None`.

Comment: Worked great! Just to be clear on your last line, I was planning to set a string value like `Foo.objects.create(value="pass")` which worked fine. I believe you meant that I cannot do `Foo.objects.create(value=pass)`?