# Storing tkinter objects in MySQL

Tags: python, mysql, oop, tkinter, python-object

Let me give you some context first.
I am making a project using tkinter, python and MySQL. In my project, every time the user clicks on *create button* in the tkinter window(which i will be calling *root* henceforth), button is created and displayed in the root window.

```
#Creating the button for that specific date
btn = tk.Button(root, text=dateoftable)       #dateoftable contains some string value
btn.number=btnnumber                          #btnnumber is a unique number for each button that increments by one everytime a new button is created
btn.place(x=x, y=y, width=100, height=100)    #x and y are predefined variables

#Adding the button object to the dictionary
tables[btnnumber]=btn                         #tables is a dictionary
```

So all the created button objects are stored in the `tables` dictionary.
Now, every time a button is added onto the root window, the tkinter button object is inserted int the MySQl table which has `btnobject`(**Primary Key**) and`dateoftable` as the names of the columns of the table `timetablebtn`. Just assume `dateoftable` to contain non-unique arbitrary string values.

```
lastelem = list(tables.values())[-1]     #gets the most recently added button object on the root window
#**The problem is in the below statement**
config.cursorobj.execute("INSERT INTO timetablebtn VALUES ('{0}','{1}')".format(str(lastelem), dateoftable))
config.mysqlobj.commit()
```

As you can see, I am storing the button object as a string in the MySQL table, which is a problem because, I cannot reference it again when I call it from the database, it just becomes a dummy string value.
So i want to know if there is a way to store objects onto MySQL. If that's not possible, I want to know if there is a way to reference the same button object when I retrieve the value from my table in the database.
If any more information is required, I will edit the question and code and post it.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not just store  the values of all attributes you need to fully recreate the object? Plenty of options to do so.

Comment: Another option - https://stackoverflow.com/q/8150078/4046632

Comment: @buran how do I store the attributes separately and later on link it to the btnobject that I am recieving from my database. Since I am recieving the object as a string literal how do I convert it back to an object and also how do I make sure that it is pointing to the same button as it was, when it was created. Also I am not aware of OOP concepts in python.

Comment: If you are not familiar with OOP it will be difficult. Every object has attributes, e.g. text, potion, size, etc. - store all the values for all attributes in a database and then reconstruct the button object. Or look at the other option that uses pickle

Comment: Saving the button object (assume it can be) is not practical because some of the options may not be the same (or even does not exists) when you load back the object, for example references to function, image and tkinter variable, etc.